# How do I correctly convert from tm to time_t?

Tags: c++, time

I want to create a tm and fill it with a specific time, then I want to subtract a certain amount of time from it.

This is what I have so far

```
time_t time_1, time_2;
struct tm tm;
struct tm tm2;

strptime("1 1 1900 12:43:40", "%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
strptime("1 1 1900 11:33:45", "%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm2);


time_1 = mktime(&tm);
time_2 = mktime(&tm2);

//    time_1  = difftime(time_2,  time_1);                                                
cout << ctime(&time_1) << endl;
cout << asctime(&tm);
```

I was planning on using difftime to calculate the difference, but ctime isn't displaying the same time as asctime, where am I going wrong?

Comment: [I'm having trouble reproducing this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b989abd9f02f4f9d). Can you come up with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is likely to be due to daylight saving time differences - i.e. the tm_isdst field of the struct tm. The call ctime(t) is equivalent to asctime(localtime(t)), so try calling just localtime(time_1) and compare the result, field by field, to tm. I would also advise not calling your variable tm as it can be confusing when it's the same name as the struct, especially as this is C++ and therefore the struct keyword is optional.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did as you said, but it didn't have any effect. My output is

"Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970", "Sun Jan  1 12:43:40 1900", "Sun Jan  1 11:33:45 1900"

The top one (the one using mktime) should be the same as the 2nd one, but it's really different for some reason.

Comment: I didn't notice earlier that you are using dates outside of the epoch, which starts from 1970. Try again with date values in 1970 or later.

Comment: Yep that was it! As long as I set the time after epoch it worked, thanks.